# Create ul li dynamically using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create dynamic `ul` and `li` tags with `<a>` inside it. I am getting `firstName` is not defined error.

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rwgoxLg2/1/)

```
var sData= [];
var temp = {
  "firstName": 'Steve',
  "route": 'url'
};

sData.push(temp);

console.log(sData);

var cList = $('ul#sParts');


$.each(sData, function(i) {
  var li = $('<li/>')
    .appendTo(cList);
  var aaa = $('<a/>')
    .text(firstName[i])
    .href(route[i])
    .appendTo(li);
});

<div class="row">
  <ul id="sParts">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'`firstName`' or '`route`' are properties of `supercededData`. So you need to define them as a part of the array.

```
$.each(supercededData, function(i) {
  var li = $('<li/>')
    .appendTo(cList);
  var aaa = $('<a/>', {
     text : supercededData[i].firstName,
     href : supercededData[i].route })
    .appendTo(li);
});
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/rwgoxLg2/2/